# SonarQube throws ''NullPointer Exception might be throw" error for variables created in java files from xsd files

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, xsd, sonarqube

I have a list of java classes generated from .xsd files. While running SonarQube it complains NullPointerException might be thrown as "_Parent" is nullable here

My xsd code is

```
<xsd:element name="Parent">
<xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:element name="ParentId" type="xsd:integer"/>
 </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="Parent">

<xsd:element name="App">
<xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:element name="Parent" minOccures="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
 </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="Parent">
```

The Parent variable is declared inside the App class as

```
protected com.sun.xml.bind.util.ListImpl _Parent;
```

```
protected com.sun.ml.bind.util.ListImpl _getParent()
{
if(_Parent == null){
_Parent = new com.sun.ml.bind.util.ListImpl(new java.util.ArrayList()}
return _Parent
}
```

It complains on the following line

```
int id =0;
final int len= ((_Parent == null)? 0 :_Parent.size());
while(id != len){ 
if(**_Parent**.get(id) instanceof java.xml.bind.Element){ context.childAsBody(((com.sun.xml.bind.JAXBObject) _Parent.get(id ++)), "Parent");
```

Can some one help me out with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: On which line of code is it complaining?

Comment: Hey @JoeC ,i have added the error line above in the question

Comment: This appears to me to be a false positive.

Comment: But is there a way to add null check condition for the _Parent variable inside the xsd files?

Comment: There is no need for this.  This is meant to be a warning from SonarQube that it _might_ be possible for a NullPointerException to be thrown there.  If you refer to my answer, you'll see that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a false positive.

If `_Parent` is null, then `id != len` will not be true, the for loop will never be entered, and the `NullPointerException` will not be thrown.